# Core Data ordered One-To-Many relation saving from background thread with new objects in multiple contexts

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

I am using Core Data in my hiking application.  I have an ordered one-to-many relationship in my data for the coordinates in a trail.  I use a background thread to sync the data and I am using a child `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for the background thread.  As best I can tell from the Apple docs on Core Data and threading I have everything set up correctly with how I use the `NSManagedObjectContext` in my threads.  Here is the problem I am running into.

1. In the background the sync process pulls down new coordinates for the trail and updates the coordinates for the trail on the child context.
2. On the main thread the user changes the trail by tracing more of it.  These new coordinates are saved to the parent context with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.
3. So now the the main thread context has new coordinates and the sync thread context has new coordinates.
4. The sync thread then saves its context and the coordinates are saved to the parent context.
5. The main thread then save its context.  The new coordinates on the main context are saved and they are added to the ordered one-to-many relationship.  They are not saved at the correct location in the ordered relationship.
6. This makes the trail "jump around."  See the black trail in the screen shot.

This seems like Core Data is doing the right thing.  It isn't deleting any of the new objects and they are all added to the relationship.  However, in this scenario I want to take just one set of coordinates from one of the context's and not have them merged together.  I can't find a way to do this.  My hack to solve this right now is to pass the object id for the trail and all of the coordinates to the main thread and save them there. I don't want to do this work on the main thread and this is a total hack.  Does anyone know of a better solution?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your NSManagedObjectContext configuration correctly. can you list your NSManagedObjectContext with parent and child as well as  concurrency type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Class of the problem**
Synchronizing ordered collection of objects between client and server.

**Order gets corrupted**
The described setup may result in conflicts on `coordinates` property. Please consider following scenario (the table represents ordered collection of coordinates):

*Child context begins synchronization. It fetches Track and its coordinates. As a result it sees the same ordered set as parent context*
Parent: `[c1, c2]`
Child: `[c1, c2]`

*Child context receives a new coordinate from the server*
Parent: `[c1, c2]`
Child: `[c1, c2, c3]`

*Parent context receives a new coordinate*
Parent: `[c1, c2, c4]`
Child: `[c1, c2, c3]`

If you save child context, order of coordinates is ambiguous.
It can be `[c1, c2, c3, c4]` or `[c1, c2, c4, c3]`, and it is not possible to decide without more information.

I have tested this scenario and unfortunately Core Data does not report this as error. It simply appends new objects from child context to coordinates from parent context `[c1, c2, c4, c3]`.

**Proposed solution**
Use non-ordered relationship and extend coordinate entity to contain timestamp (`NSDate`). It will allow you to sort coordinates.

Use `NSFetchedResultsController` to observe changes among `coordinates`. It will tell you when new coordinates are added and at what indices. This should provide enough information to redraw the path.

**Additional performance considerations**
Core Data stack described here is not the most performant option. See [this article](http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!  This was the inspiration for the what ended up being my final solution.  The key thing for me was handling order myself and doing the query myself.  I did not give all of the details about how trails can be modified, so unfortunatly the timestamp did not work.  I ended up adding a column to the coordinates for the sort order.  I also created coordinate groups. The coordinates had a group id and the trail has the group id for the coordinate set to query for.